# Resources for intermediate/advanced MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am seeking some more knowledge about MySQL queries. I've been working on building myself as a programmer and now I need to know more about MySQL advanced techniques.

I need to learn about MySQL JOIN queries, CASE, MAX..., everything that I don't already know.

I would really appreciate some links to useful articles with in-depth explanations of advanced MySQL. If you know any good video tutorial about learning MySQL, suggest it, I'm gonna purchase it.

Sorry if this question seems useless to any of you, but it's important to me since I can't keep asking SQL related questions here, I have to learn to do stuff myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you pick a real project that will require advanced MySQL and tackle it.  You'll pick up what you need along the way (and *actually* understand it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having picked up on a couple keywords (video tutorial, purchase), combined with your interest in building your skill set, I'd recommend looking into a subscription on http://www.lynda.com/

Depending on the programming language you're using in conjunction with MySQL, I'd also recommend looking into PDO (assuming you aren't already familiar with it).

Some helpful PDO articles, to supplement your existing knowledge of MySQL:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html
http://returnsuccess.com/post/15-PDO-class-Object-Oriented-PHP

I'd be more helpful, but I can only provide as much information as the question itself.